# Overriding the Django admin change_list_results.html only for some models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

I want to override the templates/admin/change_list_results.html and templates/admin/change_list.html templates for just one of my models.
How do I tell the admin to differentiate this model from all the others in my app and render a different change template than the default? 
If I just edit change_list_results.html then all the models in the admin views will reflect my changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, see documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

The short version is that you need a custom template at `admin/your-app-name/your-model-name/change_list.html` in your template path. It can be in an an app or in your root template directory.

The one catch is that Django needs to find it before it finds the default "admin/change_list.html" in `django.contrib.admin`. If it's in an app, make sure that app is listed **before** `django.contrib.admin` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. I usually just put admin template overrides in my root templates folder, since that gets loaded before apps.

Comment: This won't work for change_list_results.html as it doesn't support your-app-name/your-model-name style overrides.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO wont work because change_list_results.html is called from a template_tag -> result_list.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html#L91

https://github.com/django/django/blob/65cf82bd08631a7aa8d9dd007b2527476fa3304f/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#L288

I want to see what happens if you override or monkey patch that template tag. But import order play a lot in this.